# How to open a Xamarin Visual Studio project (sln) in Xcode on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, synchronization

Greetings dear developers. I have a problem that I cannot solve without your help. I have a Xamarin project. It was made in Visual Studio and therefore has the extension - sln. I need to open this project in Xcode 14.0.1 using Visual Studio for Mac 2019. Yes, I'm on a mac. Note: I have Xcode and Visual Studio can see it. I really need your help, thank you very much!)

[image: 1]

I need to do this in order to submit my mobile application to the AppStore. Please tell me how to do it easier.

I tried to find a solution on holy google. There they told me that I should right-click on the IOS project. And then click on the button "Remote Machine -> Open on Xcode. But I don't have such buttons.

Comment: What are you talking about?  You don't open VS solutions in XCode.  There are some specific files in a Xamarin iOS project that can be opened in XCode, but not an entire solution.

Comment: I need to open the project (the one in the image) in Xcode. Or part of this project, whatever is possible

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you said before and it doesn’t make any sense.  Can you please be more specific about exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to synchronize Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac. My task in the simplest terms is to run my Xamarin project(sln) in Xcode.

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: So I can't open my project (sln) in Xcode? Can somehow convert or something else.

Comment: If you need to publish your app to AppStore, you don't need to open your project on XCode, you can refer to Xamarin's official documentation: [App Store Distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/?tabs=macos)